# Redisson: Store tomcat httpsession to redis

Tags: session, tomcat, redisson

We are using in our project jarkata.servlet.http.HttpSession for storing attributes and the web-server is tomcat 10.

What I want is to use redisson to persist the HttpSession to redis and I followed this tutorial:
https://redisson.org/articles/redis-based-tomcat-session-management.html

When I start my application, I can't find any entry regarding Redisson or redis, also after I log in using spring-security there is nothing.

There is no entry in redis "keys *" is empty. So I am doubting that this is working, and I want to see vital sign from redisson... but nothing in the logs. Even no complaining if I set the conf file to a wrong location...

Maybe someone can help me?